3d anaglypth with xrandr (gamma) and xgamma, is that possible
I would like make left side of output (screen) red and the other blue using commands like xrandr --gamma r:g:b or xgamma -rgamma f.f -ggamma 0.000 and -bgamma f.f
Maybe blue and red, no matter ...
Is that possible?
